# Why arent my functions outputting any result?

Tags: python

This is the problem I am working through:

The program asks the user for the number of pieces of cake and the number of party-goers, in that order. Print the number of pieces of cake each party-goer receives and the number of pieces of cake left over

My code:

```
pieces_cake = int(input('Number of pieces of cake:'))
party_goers = int(input('Number of party-goers: '))

def cake_per_person(pieces_cake, party_goers):
    cake_per_person = pieces_cake//party_goers
    return cake_per_person
def leftover_cake(pieces_cake, party_goers):
    leftover_cake = pieces_cake % party_goers
    return leftover_cake


print(f"Each party-goer recieves {cake_per_person} pieces of cake\n Pieces of cake that won't be distributed: {leftover_cake}")
```

Output:

```
Number of pieces of cake:12
Number of party-goers: 5
Each party-goer recieves <function cake_per_person at 0x000001947A3C51F0> pieces of cake
 Pieces of cake that won't be distributed: <function leftover_cake at 0x000001947A5B7EE0>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not calling the functions.

Comment: You're forgetting to call the functions (e.g. `cake_per_person()` instead of `cake_per_person`). Right now you're just printing the function objects themselves.

Comment: FYI typo in "recieves" and "partygoer" is not typically hyphenated.

Comment: Add () to your functions: "recieves {cake_per_person()} pieces"

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515928/new-to-programming-dont-understand-why-i-cant-get-this-variable-to-print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling the functions, just printing them.
The correct line should probably be:

```
print(f"Each party-goer recieves {cake_per_person(pieces_cake, party_goers)} pieces of cake\n Pieces of cake that won't be distributed: {leftover_cake(pieces_cake, party_goers)}")
```